# Sufficient conditions for equal marginal medians

Tags: probability, median, marginal-distribution

Let $X, Y$ be dependent random variables taking values on the same set (either a finite set, an interval or the real line). I'd like to know if there's any condition on $P(Y|X)$ which ensures that
$$\text{median}(X) = \text{median}(Y).$$

Let me give an example of the type of conditions I'm looking for, but using the mean instead of the median. For the mean, if $\mathbb E(Y|X=x) = x$, $\forall x$, then
$$\mathbb E(Y) = \mathbb E(X).$$

Does something like this hold for the median?

**EDIT:** Let me give more context to the problem. Variable $X$ is a RV whose median I want to estimate. I have only access to noisy observations $y_i \sim  Y | X = x_i$. I would like to know in which cases one can estimate the median of $X$ as the median of $Y$.

For example, if $(X,Y)$ are jointly Gaussian, then $\text{median}(Y) = \text{median}(X)$. But this is too restrictive. In particular, I don't know much about the distribution of $X$. So I'm interested in knowing if there are conditions/properties of the noise distribution (the distribution of $Y|X$) that would justify estimating the $\text{median}(X)$ as the $\text{median}(Y)$, regardless of the distribution of $X$ (or for a general class of distributions for $X$).

Comment: This is awfully vague--it reads like you don't have a question but are searching for one.  The problem is that there are myriad possible answers but we have no hints concerning which ones might be relevant to you.  Could you share your motivation?  Is there some question of statistical interest that underlies it?

Comment: I edited the question adding the motivation. I hope it clarifies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose your distribution is jointly continuous with joint density $p_{X,Y}$.  Letting $m_X \equiv \text{median}(X)$ and $m_Y \equiv \text{median}(Y)$, the defining equation for these quantities is:

$$\frac{1}{2} = \int \limits_{-\infty}^\infty \int \limits_{-\infty}^{m_X} p_{X,Y}(x,y) \ dx \ dy = \int \limits_{-\infty}^{m_Y} \int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} p_{X,Y}(x,y) \ dx \ dy.$$

Any condition that renders $m_X = m_Y$ in this equation is a sufficient condition for equivalence of median.  One very strong sufficient condition is **exchangeability** (i.e., $p_{X,Y}(x,y) = p_{X,Y}(y,x)$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$), which would make all of the quantiles equal in both marginal distributions.  Weaker conditions exist, but they are not very illuminating, and I am not aware of any way of writing the conditions other than to say that $m_X = m_Y$ in the above equation.  You might be able to find a weaker sufficient condition by splitting the joint density into a marginal and conditional density and then imposing some form or condition on the latter.  The above definining equation should serve as a basis for that inquiry.